# Retrieve specific data from JSON using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

HI from the following snippet of JSON:

```
 "comments":{
            "count":2,
            "data":[
               {
                  "created_time":"1436046658",
                  "text":"Omg!!!! \u00bf!Pediste fondue?!",
                  "from":{
                     "username":"shanlynch",
                     "profile_picture":"https:\/\/instagramimages-a.akamaihd.net\/profiles\/profile_3904583_75sq_1379476264.jpg",
                     "id":"3904583",
                     "full_name":"shanlynch"
                  },
                  "id":"1021955900254028526"
               },
               {
                  "created_time":"1436049741",
                  "text":"Jajaa en el verano no hay fondue \ud83d\ude2f",
                  "from":{
                     "username":"elisamb9",
                     "profile_picture":"https:\/\/igcdn-photos-g-a.akamaihd.net\/hphotos-ak-xfa1\/t51.2885-19\/10852622_602060126561478_497106753_a.jpg",
                     "id":"209354191",
                     "full_name":""
                  },
                  "id":"1021981758431789771"
               }
            ]
         },
```

I would like to retrieve the "text" value from the username "shanlynch" using Angular in an ng-repeat loop, but not sure how would I go about it.

I know how to do this basic one like so but not sure on the above:

Example:

```
 "images":{
            "low_resolution":{
               "url":"https:\/\/scontent.cdninstagram.com\/hphotos-xaf1\/t51.2885-15\/s320x320\/e15\/11385601_1616392095286197_1575756416_n.jpg",
               "width":320,
               "height":320
            }
}
```

Angular ng-repeat loop:

```
   <li ng-repeat="p in pics">
                        <a href="#" target="_blank"><img ng-src="{{p.images.low_resolution.url}}" /></a>
                    </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Supposing you have

```
$scope.comments; //Your JSON (content inside data)
```

You can do

```
<li ng-repeat="comment in comments">
  <span ng-if="comment.from.username === 'shanlynch'">{{comment.text}}</span>
</li>
```

Comment: Sorry, but it will not work. You have missed the "data" property inside comments object.

Comment: @SumanBarick that is why i added my comment where it says "(content inside data). $scope.comments should contain comments.data (from JSON)

Answer (score 0):

Have the required data array in a $scope variable

```
var jsonData; //Put your JSON data in it
$scope.dataArr = jsonData.comments.data;
```

Now, you can do like this, loop over all the data object (named "dat" to avoid confusion) inside your data array, and pick the right one.

```
<li ng-repeat="dat in dataArr">
  <span ng-if="dat.from.username === 'shanlynch'">{{dat.text}}</span>
</li>
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

btw is your json valid ? please validate json at http://jsonlint.com/

If its valid JSON then below code should work

```
  <li ng-repeat="comment in comments.data">
      <span ng-if="comment.from.username === 'shanlynch'">{{comment.text}}</span>
    </li>
```